# Grab - заполнение формы, отправление сообщения

Tags: python, grab

Хочу запостить сообщение на сайте, из grab документации для проверки взял несколько методов - то что находит fire bug кликая на форму:

> <textarea
> onfocus="Wall.showEditPost()"
> onkeydown="onCtrlEnter(event,
> Wall.sendPost)"
> onkeyup="Wall.postChanged()"
> class="fl_l" id="post_field"
> style="height: 32px; overflow: hidden;
> resize: none;"></textarea>

методы которые предоставляет grab - **set__input** - не подходит т.к нету тарибута name
 **set__input_by_id**('postfield', 'Hello World') - вообщем этот метод выдает ошибку Index list error
и последний метод **set_input_by__number**('1', 'hello world') - выдает ошибку, grab.error.DataNotFound: Response does not contains any form

И в итоге не знаю, как подобраться к форме, т.к она не стандартна, как бывает обычно: <input name="post"></input> и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

g = Grab(log_file="out.html") 
посмотрите в лог возможно поле подгружается средствами js

Comment: спасибо за догадки, там все на js держиться, родительского тега form не видно, поэтому там только http запрос эмулировать(я к такому выводу пришел)